# change id of elements in a reusable xml layout

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have an xml file that contains a reusable layout that i want to be added when the user clicks a button.
**inputs.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/add"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_blue"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/amount"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_blue"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textview"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity=""
        android:text="@string/category"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_blue"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This layout is loaded into a fragment **budgetFragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.dashboard.fragments.BudgetFrag">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/budget_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="17dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floating"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

the elements get loaded as I need them to but only one problem, all the elements have the same id which comes from the last element loaded.

```
    private BudgetViewModel mViewModel;
    private LinearLayout layout = null;
    private TextView textView;
    private Button button;
    private EditText editText;
    private ViewGroup viewGroup;
    private View viewer;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private static String TAG = "BudgetFrag :: ";

 @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bugdet_fragment, container, false);
        viewGroup = container;
        return v;
    }

    public int findUnusedId(LinearLayout layout) {
        int fID = 0;
        while (layout.findViewById(++fID) != null) ;
        return fID;
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(BudgetViewModel.class);

        // TODO: Use the ViewModel

    }
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        FloatingActionButton add_elements = view.findViewById(R.id.floating);
        layout = view.findViewById(R.id.budget_layout);
        add_elements.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                View view = getDialog(getActivity(), layout);
                layout.addView(view);
            }
        });
    }
    public View getDialog(Context context, final LinearLayout layout) {
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        viewer = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.buget_input, viewGroup, false);
        AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        b.setTitle("Select A Category");
        String[] types = {"Food", "Entertainment"};
        final String[] selected = {""};
        b.setItems(types, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                textView = viewer.findViewById(R.id.textview);
                switch (which) {
                    case 0:
                        textView.setText("Food");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        textView.setText("Entertainment");
                        break;
                }
                editText = viewer.findViewById(R.id.edittext);
                Log.d(TAG, "DialogInterface :: editText :: " + editText.getId());
                editText.setId(findUnusedId(layout));
                button = viewer.findViewById(R.id.btn);
                button.setId(findUnusedId(layout));
                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "setOnClickListener :: editText :: " + editText.getId());
                        if(!editText.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "textView.getId()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.d(TAG, "setOnClickListener :: "+ editText.getText().toString());
                        }
                    }
                });
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }).show();
        return viewer;
    }
```

the **getDialog** method is where the action happens.
All three elements have the same id as the last added input layout elements.
the question is how can i make each added input layout is unique to be able to get the edittext data? how do i change the ids dynamically as the elememnts are being added?

**ps.** the number of input layout that can be added is *infinite*.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a tricky method to handle this problem. First create instance variable like

```
ArrayList<RootView> rootViews = new ArrayList(); Then we have to generate our own ID to each Root View and its corresponding child views and put it inside above rootViews list.
```

Look below :

```
  LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linear);
  TextView textView = linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.tv);
  EditText editText = linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.et);
  Button button = linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.btn);

  int uniqueLinearLayoutId = View.generateViewId();
  int uniqueTextViewId = View.generateViewId();
  int uniqueFirstEditTextId = View.generateViewId();
  int uniqueBtnId = View.generateViewId();
  ArrayList<Integer> childViews = new ArrayList<>();
  childViews.add(uniqueTextViewId);
  childViews.add(uniqueFirstEditTextId);
  childViews.add(uniqueBtnId);

  rootViews.add(new RootView(uniqueLinearLayoutId,childViews));
```

Now we have structured our view id's inside rootViews list. So, now we can identify each view as they have unique id's.